# How to avoid errors when querying BigQuery with Data Studio?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio that uses fetches from a Google Big Query View. I am running into "Quota Error: Too many concurrent queries. I was thinking of getting around this by using batched queries.

Any other solutions to get around the error are welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch queries won't help in this case - Data Studio would not know how to retrieve the batched results.

My preferred option for these cases is to copy the query results out of BigQuery into temporary storage (sheets, GCS, MySQL...) and have Data Studio read the results from there. The best place depends on the shape of your data and the results you are trying to visualize.

Other options - depending on your exact use case:

- Turn on caching in Data Studio, which will prefetch data and run queries against cache.
- Materialize the view, so that the queries will run faster.
- Reduce the number of components on the page so that they don't generate as many queries.

(This answer might change depending on future Data Studio updates)

Comment: Thanks Felipe, how would I accomplish materialized view in BigQuery?

Comment: @Jason BigQuery views are not materialized.  Read the limitations here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations